# React Native Expo SQLite is not executing all transactions in statement

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo

I have code that can be simplified to the following:

```
database.transaction(tx => {
    tx.executeSql(
        `
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${TABLE_NAMES.Metadata} (
            theme TEXT CHECK( theme IN ('dark', 'light') ),
            tutorialCompleteDate INTEGER,
            userEmail TEXT,
            lastPaymentDate INTEGER,
            lastExportDate INTEGER,
            lastUseDate INTEGER
        );
        INSERT INTO ${TABLE_NAMES.Metadata} 
            (theme, tutorialCompleteDate, userEmail, lastExportDate, lastUseDate)
            VALUES ('dark', null, null, null, ${new Date().getTime()});
        `,
        params,
        (_, result) => { resolve(result) },
        (_, error) => { console.log(error); reject(error); return true; }
    );
});
```

I can see that the top "CREATE TABLE" statement is executing, but the INSERT INTO is not creating a record.

Even stranger, if I make the INSERT query invalid (by adding an extra argument for example), I get an error. But with a valid INSERT query, I get no error and no record inserted.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about SQLite inserts?

Answer (score 0):

I completely misread the documentation. You need to split this into two different transactions. I decided to just open a new `database.transaction` call each time, so it looked more like this:

```js
database.transaction(tx => {
    tx.executeSql(
        `
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${TABLE_NAMES.Metadata} (
            theme TEXT CHECK( theme IN ('dark', 'light') ),
            tutorialCompleteDate INTEGER,
            userEmail TEXT,
            lastPaymentDate INTEGER,
            lastExportDate INTEGER,
            lastUseDate INTEGER
        );
        `,
        params,
        (_, result) => { resolve(result) },
        (_, error) => { console.log(error); reject(error); return true; }
    );
});

database.transaction(tx => {
    tx.executeSql(
        `
        INSERT INTO ${TABLE_NAMES.Metadata} 
            (theme, tutorialCompleteDate, userEmail, lastExportDate, lastUseDate)
            VALUES ('dark', null, null, null, ${new Date().getTime()});
        `,
        params,
        (_, result) => { resolve(result) },
        (_, error) => { console.log(error); reject(error); return true; }
    );
});
```